# Index Match Less Than but greater than as an array

Tags: excel-formula

I have a sheet of data with industry descriptions based on SIC codes in this format:

[image]

On another sheet I have SIC codes per groups. I am looking for a formula entered as an array that returns the industry description based on whether or not the SIC is greater than or equal the low but less than or equal than the high value. This is what I was able to find but only works for one industry because it is an exact match.

[image]

```
{=INDEX (RATES! BC: BC, MATCH (MIN (IF (RATES! AZ: AZ<=[@[SIC Code]],ABS (RATES! AZ: AZ-[@[SIC Code]]),IF (RATES! BA: BA>='EB Sold Case Demographics'!T2, ABS (RATES! BA: BA-[@[SIC Code]]),0)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget the second column, use this normal formula:

```
=VLOOKUP([@[SIC Code]],RATES!AZ:BC,4,TRUE)
```